# Does a web interface exist for configuring log4j?

Tags: java, web, logging, interface, log4j

I need a web interface for configure log4j that gives me:

- CRUD of loggers, appenders and filters
- when I am OK with the configuration I want to click and download an xml version of the configuration
- hierarchical view of the configured loggers which expands as needed (nice to have).

I am aware of this [old thread](http://osdir.com/ml/jakarta.log4j.user/2003-05/msg00091.html) but I can't find the log4j-sandbox nor the ConfigurationServlet they were talking about.

Answer (score 3):

The above mentioned files you can find [here](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/UsefulCode) (ConfigurationServlet) and [here](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/AppContainerLogging) (log4j-sandbox). Hope it helps.

Don't know myself of any log4j configuration generator. [This blog entry](http://hillert.blogspot.com/2008/11/configure-logback-from-your-web.html) has some kind of web interface you are partly looking for, but it's designed for SLF4J and Logback, the successor of log4j.